# performance drops when using SKShader

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, shader

I've taken a look at SKShader to get some watery effects in an app where a some sprites are moving around.  Based on this tutorial [Making a Pixel Shader for iOS8 with Sprite Kit](http://www.ymc.ch/en/making-a-pixel-shader-for-ios8-with-sprite-kit), I've created an effect but my frame rate drops way down in the simulator and I get memory issues in an iPhone 5s.

My code is shown below
from GameScene:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        super.didMoveToView(view)

        // MARK: BACKGROUND IMAGE & SHADER

        let backgroundImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
        backgroundImage.size.width = frame.size.width
        backgroundImage.size.height = frame.size.height
        backgroundImage.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame), CGRectGetMidY(frame))
        backgroundImage.zPosition = -1000
        addChild(backgroundImage)

        let shaderContainer = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0), size: (CGSizeMake(frame.width, frame.height)))
        shaderContainer.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2)
        shaderContainer.zPosition = 1000
        addChild(shaderContainer)

        let shader = SKShader(fileNamed: "shader_water.fsh")
        shader.uniforms = [
            SKUniform(name: "size", floatVector3:GLKVector3Make(Float(self.frame.size.width), Float(self.frame.size.height), 0)),
        ]
        shaderContainer.shader = shader
```

The .fsh file is taken straight from the tutorial.

```
void main( void )
{
    float time = u_time * .5;
    vec2 sp = gl_FragCoord.xy / size.xy;
    vec2 p = sp * 6.0 - 20.0;
    vec2 i = p;
    float c = 1.0;
    float inten = .05;

    for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++)
    {
        float t = time * (1.0 - (3.5 / float(n+1)));
        i = p + vec2(cos(t - i.x) + sin(t + i.y), sin(t - i.y) + cos(t + i.x));
        c += 1.0/length(vec2(p.x / (sin(i.x+t)/inten),p.y / (cos(i.y+t)/inten)));
    }

    c /= float(5);
    c = 1.55-sqrt(c);
    vec3 colour = vec3(pow(abs(c), 15.0));

    gl_FragColor = vec4(clamp(colour + vec3(0.0, 0.17, 0.3), 0.0, .5), 0.3);
}
```

Does anyone know what might be going on and how I can get a shader to work more efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire calculation in your fragment shader is based on `u_time` & `gl_FragCoord` which mean the same calculations can be moved to your vertex shader. Some basic tips to improve your shader performance.

- Do all calculation per vertex and avoid per fragment calculations
- Avoid loops (for loop in your case) in shader, GPU is not good at
  looping

Comment: Thanks for the response. SpriteKit doesn't appear to have a vertex shader (from this answer to another question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597314/vertex-shader-in-spritekit). Do you have some code ideas how to move  calculating per vertex or remove the for loop?  The fragment shader in the tutorial appears to be based on https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MdlXz8

Comment: Seems SpriteKit does not allow vertex shader, so the only choice is to move away from it if it is not too late and use OpenGL ES 2.0. There are many ways to optimise the shader, but you first need to implement a runnable vert and frag shaders.

Comment: Moving to a new environment seems drastic for a watery image effect. I wondered if I could increase the tile size to create a "watered down" version of the reflection effect (so fewer reflections), would that significantly decrease the CPU overhead. I'm not sure how to change that in the fragment shader though.